# Is there a "URL-Structure" for Users and Groups I can access via Hyperlink?

Tags: development, web-part, url, hyperlink, spgridview

I have a Custom WebPart which gets credentials from the site into a GridView-Table. The result (user and credential) is shown as strings. I want to create a Hyperlink to the users e.g. mysite, instead using strings. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are built in web-parts for this, but I always feel they aren't quite right.

So what you need to access is:

SPWeb > SPGroupCollection > ForEach SPGroup > ForEach SPGroup.Users > SPUser.OwnedGroups

Then display out your tree like:

Users > Groups

or

Groups > Users

The code for getting the properties is:

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPSite);
UserProfileManager manager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
UserProfile profile = manager.GetUserProfile(oUser.ToString());
ProfileValueCollectionBase FirstName = profile.GetProfileValueCollection("FirstName");
ProfileValueCollectionBase LastName = profile.GetProfileValueCollection("LastName");

if (profile["PictureURL"].Value != null)
{
    ProfileValueCollectionBase baseVal = profile.GetProfileValueCollection("PictureURL");
}
else
{
     //Default image
}

var userUrl = profile.PersonalUrl
```

Comment: Hi Hugh, thanks for your answer. I have the URL as a string in a Datatable and want to create a Hyperlink out of the URL. I tried to build a html in the datatable. But the datatable does not accept html, only Content :) Do you know how I can make a string-url in a datatable(gridview) into a Hyperlink?

Comment: From code behind, you would have to override the renderer. Or have it print out in some sort of pseudo tags that a javascript function updates on page? The two things that instantly come to mind for fixing that.